# Removing individual markers from map

Tags: leaflet, events

I have a map with several moving markers on it and have been trying to remove each individual one when their respective animation ends. I am using Leaflet and Leaflet's plugin *Leaflet.MovingMarker*. I tried using methods *isEnded()* and *end* without much sucess.

With the latter method (*end*), the following code removes only but one marker (full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/o53njksy/132/)):

```
marker.on('end', function() {
  map.removeLayer(this);
  });
```

With a *click* event instead of an *end* event, each marker is made easily removable, but then this is not what I am looking for:

```
marker.on('click', function() {
  map.removeLayer(this);
  });
```

With the method *isEnded()*, have not had any luck at all either (full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/o53njksy/133/)):

```
var ended = marker.isEnded(); 

  if (ended = true) {
  console.log("this marker ended!");
  map.removeLayer(this);
  }
```

I wonder what I am missing here?

Comment: Tried using _isRunning()_ with _setInterval_, at no avail either. Full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/o53njksy/145/). I am guessing that the problem resides in my unability to select each one of the markers individually (as when one clicks each one of them).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the 'end' event by adding it to the marker's declaration:

```
 var marker = L.Marker.movingMarker(coordinates, [6000]).on('end', 
    function(e) {
        console.log('end move');          
    });
```

I couldn't get the layer to be removed, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912145/leaflet-how-to-find-existing-markers-and-delete-markers) are some solutions for how to remove individual markers.

Comment: The problem is, this will only remove one marker, not each one of them when they reach the end position.